# wbhook to local node.js server via ngrok, will service triggering Webhooks need password?

Tags: node.js, ngrok

I've set up a tunnel using ngrok. I did so mainly to be able to get callbacks from services our server integrates with via Webhooks, while running on local machine during development and testing.

I reserved a domain, example:

```
123.ngrok.io
```

When I run my server locally, the tunnel is setup and I can hit it via browser going to `123.ngrok.io`, but, when I do so, the browser asks me to authenticate:

[image]

My question is this:

Will the service calling the Webhooks to 123.ngrok.io be required to authenticate? If so, I have no idea how to make that work.

Ultimately I need the Webhooks to run like they do when hitting live, no auth needed.

Is ngrok going to block the Webhooks calls from various services due to authentication?

UPDATE:

I have tested the Webhooks hitting my reserved ngrok domain, example, `123.ngrok.io`. The service that hits that Webhook at that domain is triggered but returns `401 Unauthorized`.

It seems like ngrok is not letting the Webhook through. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually got rid of the 401 error when services were trying to hit the reserved domain by commenting out the auth line in the connect call on ngrok:

```
const result = await ngrok.connect({
            proto: 'http',
            addr: PORT,
            // auth: `${process.env.NGROK_USER}:${process.env.NGROK_PSW}`,
            subdomain: '123' // reserved tunnel name 123.ngrok.io
        })
```

This fixed my problem.